# How to ignore Spring data validation on login form?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm using Spring MVC to make a webapp.
My user model

```
public class User {

@NotNull(message="First name cannot be blank")
@Size(min=2, max=30, message="First name must be between 2 and 30 characters")
private String firstName;

@NotNull(message="Last name cannot be blank")
@Size(min=2, max=30, message="Last name must be between 2 and 30 characters")
private String lastName;

@NotNull(message="Email cannot be blank")
@Size(min=10, max=50, message="Email must be between 10 and 50 characters")
private String email;

@NotNull(message="Phone number cannot be blank")
@Size(min=10, max=11, message="Phone number must be between 10 and 11 characters")
private String phoneNum;

@NotNull(message="Username cannot be blank")
@Size(min=3, max=30, message="Username must be between 2 and 30 characters")
private String username;

@NotNull(message="Password cannot be blank")
@Size(min=5, max=50, message="Password must be between 5 and 50 characters")
private String password;


public User(String username, String password)
{
    super();
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
}
/**
 * 
 */
public User() {
    super();
}
/**
 * @param firstName
 * @param lastName
 * @param email
 * @param phoneNum
 * @param username
 * @param password
 */
public User(String firstName, String lastName, String email, String phoneNum, String username, String password) {
    super();
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.email = email;
    this.phoneNum = phoneNum;
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
}
```

My registration has form inputs for all these fields, however the login only uses the username and password.
All fields are required for the project. 
I have my login form set to use the constructor that take a username and password. On submit it follows the data validation for all the user model variables.
LoginController:

```
@RequestMapping(path="login", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView displayLoginForm()
{
    return new ModelAndView("login", "user", new User("", ""));
}


@RequestMapping(path="loginuser", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView loginUser(@Valid @ModelAttribute("user")User u, BindingResult result)
{
    if(result.hasErrors())
    {
        return new ModelAndView("login", "user", u);
    }
```

Is it possible to tell the method to ignore all the variables except username and password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a way, however, what can I suggest is to change approach.

Create a new POJO called, for example, AuthUser which will have only username and password to validate.

Your web application will benefit of a "slimmer" object to pass to a Controller, and if it is a valid user than use that AuthUser to hit the database to retrieve a proper User using a query.

What you are trying to do is not a good practice, due to the fact that you are trying to populate a Model already in the controller. This should be a responsibility of the Database.I reccomend you to see DTO design pattern as well it may helps you.